# In a GeoJson file, how do I combine features (states) into a single feature (region)

Tags: geojson, gdal

I'm drawing a map of the US with D3.  Problem is the design on the project has changed and I need to draw regions as a whole instead of the individual states.  I can't for the life of me find any good info on how to combine state features into a single region feature.

I'm assuming the gdal is the right tool for the job, but I can't seem to find how to do this.

Comment: I don't know much about GDAL, but you could use ogr2ogr (related to GDAL) to load JSON to Postgis and then use ST_Union to merge features. You could also use the Javascript Topogology Suite, https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts, which will read GeoJSON, and then again you would union them together. You haven't stated enough about your environment and desired tools to be able to help much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial Mike T posted is a great resource, but it didn't solve the specific problem I had.

What I finally discovered is that when you're using [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) there is a topojson.merge method to combine multiple paths into a single path.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [**this tutorial**](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) to convert a Shapefile into GeoJSON, then to [**TopoJSON**](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson), then to a D3 project.  There is even [an example of US (counties?) included with v1.6.27 of the project](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/blob/v1.6.27/examples/us-10m.json).